# Start-Process: Access is denied (even though i've provided credentials

Tags: powershell, permissions

I am getting the following error when trying to execute a line of code

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: 
Access is denied.
```

This is the code being executed

```
$username = "domain\username"
$passwordPlainText = "password"     
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "$passwordPlainText" -asplaintext -force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$password

$powershellArguments = "D:\path\ps.script.ps1", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -credential $cred -ArgumentList $powershellArguments -wait
```

- This code works fine when executed locally, but not when called via vbs WMI
- Both computers exist in the same domain and address range
- The username and password supplied have admin privileges on both machines
- I have tried both with and without `-wait` however neither works, and due to the user being privileged, I'd prefer to keep it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Have you tried without the "-wait"?

Look at this link:

> - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/3983a1e4-a663-47df-86f6-874d1828ea61/
>
> The parameter "-wait" suppresses the command prompt or retains the
>   window until the process completes. This operation may require
>   administrator rights.

Comment: however, even with -wait, the username and password i'm using have full access to the box, so it shouldn't be an issue that it requires admin rights