# Run a powershell script as administrator with credentials inside of the script

Tags: powershell, administrator

Im trying to run a script as an administrator with the administrator username and password within the script. I know this isnt best practice but Im working on a project where this is a one time use. Ive tried so many way to do this to no avail.
Invoke-Command
Start-Process
Disabled UAC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Start-Process in Powershell using user credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758651/how-to-run-start-process-in-powershell-using-user-credentials)

Comment: No. I tried the code from that page (see below) but get an error.
```
$username = "user"

$password = "pass"


$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))


Start-Process powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory C:\testScript.ps1 -Credential ($credentials)

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question with the exact error message and at which command it occurred. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do not use brackets around variables as: `$credentials`.